# Can't loading css in JSF

Tags: jsf

I'm using the JSF 2.2. I can't add `.css` in my `.xhtml` page.
Code in `.xhtml`

```
<h:head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet library="resources/css" name="style.css" id="cascade1"/>
```

Also I tried declare it into a `<h:head>` with the same result.
FireBug is seeing this resource but it is showing message:

> Reload the page to get source for .../javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml;...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use the `library` attribute:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css"  />
```

This way, the JSF servlet expects the `style.css` file to be in `/resources/css` path.

Comment: This is actually wrong usage of `library`. OP should have used `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used